# How to remove unwanted namespaces and change the namespace location in Spring Web Service requests

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

I am working on a Spring Web services client, which is making a SOAP requests.

The project contains a wsdl file which references 2 versions of xsd files.  The issue we are observing is that the generated request includes all the namespaces, even those which are not applicable. Also we want the namespaces to appear in SOAP-ENV. Below are sample actual and expected requests with dummy data.

EmployeeSearchRequest is defined in empService-v1-1.xsd

**Actual Request:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
...
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns6:EmployeeSearchRequest xmlns:ns2="http://employee-info.com/emp/xsd/2014/05" xmlns:ns3="http://employee-info.com/emp/common/xsd/2014/09" xmlns:ns4="http://employee-info.com/emp/xsd/2011/04" xmlns:ns5="http://employee-info.com/emp/wsdl/empService-v1-0" xmlns:ns6="http://employee-info.com/emp/wsdl/empService-v1-1">emp1</ns6:EmployeeSearchRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Expected Request:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://employee-info.com/emp/common/xsd/2014/09" xmlns:ns2="http://employee-info.com/emp/wsdl/empService-v1-1">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
...
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:EmployeeSearchRequest>emp1</ns2:EmployeeSearchRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I could not figure out how can I achieve the expected request format. Could not find solutions online as well.
This is first time I am working on SOAP web service.

Please help.